# Producer Consumer using wait / notifyAll

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProducerConsumerExample {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        List<Integer> taskQueue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          int MAX_CAPACITY = 5;
          Thread tProducer = new Thread(new Producer(MAX_CAPACITY, taskQueue), "Producer");
          Thread tConsumer = new Thread(new Consumer(taskQueue), "Consumer");
          tProducer.start();
          tConsumer.start();
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable{

    List<Integer> taskQueue;
    
    public Consumer(List<Integer> taskQueue) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            consume();
        }
    }
    
    private void consume() {
        synchronized (taskQueue) {
            while(taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Empty, waiting for more elements");
                    taskQueue.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            int i = taskQueue.remove(0);
            System.out.println("Consumed "+i);
            taskQueue.notifyAll();
        }
        
    }
    
}
class Producer implements Runnable{

    final int MAX_CAPACITY;
    List<Integer> taskQueue;
    int counter;
    
    public Producer(int capacity, List<Integer> taskQueue) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
        this.MAX_CAPACITY = capacity;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            produce(counter++);
        }
    }
    
    private void produce(int value) {
        
        synchronized (taskQueue) {
            while(taskQueue.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {
                try {
                    taskQueue.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            taskQueue.add(value);
            System.out.println("Produced "+value);
            taskQueue.notifyAll();
        }
        
    }
}
```

The output for the above program should be random order b/w producer & consumer.
Like

```
Produced 0 
Consumed 0 
and soon
```

But I am getting the output(always)

```
Produced 0
Produced 1
Produced 2
Produced 3
Produced 4
Consumed 0
Consumed 1
Consumed 2
Consumed 3
Consumed 4
Empty, waiting for more elements
```

What am I missing here?

Also, If I places a sysout in produce function at the beginning(before synchronized, they starts coming random)

Comment: Why do you thing that output should looks like: "Produced 0 
Consumed 0  Produced 1 Consumed 1 " when you've write multi threading  code. This is parallel execution is in it ?

Comment: Because two threads running in parallel, so output should be mix of two threads. Something from producer thread & something from consumer thread. Basically what should happen here as soon as element is there in queue, it should get consumed which is not happening. It is getting consumed once queue is full.

Comment: The producer is holding the task list locked while waiting

Comment: Also I do not necessarily wants producer  0 consumer 0 producer 1 consumer 1 and so on. I just want they should run in parallel like producer 0 producer 1 consumer 0 and so on.

Comment: How threads are actually executed depends on many things like operating system, time sharing policy. Making any assumptions on order of thread execution leads to situations like yours, you expect some behavior and reality doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: @Ankit Bansal Ok then, why don't you start with removing your `Thread.sleep(100);` and `Thread.sleap(1000);` and continue your experiments :)

Comment: Done that. Still the same result

Comment: I got it worked like I wanted by breaking a syncrhornized block into parts, one above sleep & one below sleep, But what is the reason? @VictorGubin

Answer (score 2):

That's a little too long to just put in a comment.
Just to show you what I meant that you can't make any assumptions about order of execution of threads I ran your code without changes on my machine and here's the output:

```
Produced 0
Consumed 0
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 1
Consumed 1
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 2
Consumed 2
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 3
Consumed 3
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 4
Consumed 4
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 5
Consumed 5
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 6
Consumed 6
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 7
Consumed 7
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 8
Consumed 8
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 9
Consumed 9
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 10
Produced 11
Produced 12
Produced 13
Consumed 10
Consumed 11
Consumed 12
Consumed 13
Empty, waiting for more elements
Produced 14
Consumed 14
Empty, waiting for more elements
```

Your code is fine but you make false assumptions about what is should do.
You made a statement and I quote: `"Because two threads running in parallel, so output should be mix of two threads."` - no it should not, it might, but to depend on it is wrong.
How threads are actually executed depends on many things like operating system, time sharing policy and many more. Making any assumptions on order of thread execution leads to situations like yours, you expect some behavior and reality doesn't meet your expectations.